# Linux: ld does not find dynamic library, even though file exists

Tags: linux, ld

I'm trying to build a Qt application, which involves a call to `uic`. I am on Ubuntu 22.04 (on WSL1, though that should hopefully not make a difference). I installed the necessary packages, but I cannot invoke `uic`:

```
❯ /usr/lib/qt5/bin/uic
/usr/lib/qt5/bin/uic: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Core.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have covered the usual bases. The usual symlinks and the actual library exist:

```
❯ ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1210 Aug 10 10:37 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.prl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      20 Aug 10 10:37 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so -> libQt5Core.so.5.15.3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      20 Aug 10 10:37 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 -> libQt5Core.so.5.15.3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      20 Aug 10 10:37 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.15 -> libQt5Core.so.5.15.3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5613992 Aug 10 10:37 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.15.3
❯ file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.15.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.15.3: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=4745cda28772e27ab5124c79ddc26da084782cee, for GNU/Linux 3.17.0, stripped
```

My `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` looks okay (it's usually more complex, I simplified it for debugging):

```
❯ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Let's look at what `ld` actually does (the full log is long, therefore I moved it to the end):

```
❯ LD_DEBUG=all /usr/lib/qt5/bin/uic
[…]
      6223:     file=libQt5Core.so.5 [0];  needed by /usr/lib/qt5/bin/uic [0]
      6223:     find library=libQt5Core.so.5 [0]; searching
      6223:      search path=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v3:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/haswell/x86_64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/haswell:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/haswell/x86_64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/haswell:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu          (system search path)
[…]
      6223:       trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:      search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      6223:      search path=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v3:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/haswell/x86_64:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/haswell:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/haswell/x86_64:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/haswell:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v3:/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2:/lib/tls/haswell/x86_64:/lib/tls/haswell:/lib/tls/x86_64:/lib/tls:/lib/haswell/x86_64:/lib/haswell:/lib/x86_64:/lib:/usr/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v3:/usr/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2:/usr/lib/tls/haswell/x86_64:/usr/lib/tls/haswell:/usr/lib/tls/x86_64:/usr/lib/tls:/usr/lib/haswell/x86_64:/usr/lib/haswell:/usr/lib/x86_64:/usr/lib            (system search path)
[…]
      6223:
/usr/lib/qt5/bin/uic: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Core.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So, according to `ld`'s debug output, it actually 'tries' a file that is a valid symlink to the library we need. Still it fails to load the library, without any further debug output.

At this point, I'm at a loss. What else can I do to track this down?

### Omitted Full ld Debug Log

```
❯ LD_DEBUG=all /usr/lib/qt5/bin/uic
      6223:     symbol=__vdso_clock_gettime;  lookup in file=linux-vdso.so.1 [0]
      6223:     binding file linux-vdso.so.1 [0] to linux-vdso.so.1 [0]: normal symbol `__vdso_clock_gettime' [LINUX_2.6]
      6223:     symbol=__vdso_gettimeofday;  lookup in file=linux-vdso.so.1 [0]
      6223:     binding file linux-vdso.so.1 [0] to linux-vdso.so.1 [0]: normal symbol `__vdso_gettimeofday' [LINUX_2.6]
      6223:     symbol=__vdso_time;  lookup in file=linux-vdso.so.1 [0]
      6223:     binding file linux-vdso.so.1 [0] to linux-vdso.so.1 [0]: normal symbol `__vdso_time' [LINUX_2.6]
      6223:     symbol=__vdso_getcpu;  lookup in file=linux-vdso.so.1 [0]
      6223:     binding file linux-vdso.so.1 [0] to linux-vdso.so.1 [0]: normal symbol `__vdso_getcpu' [LINUX_2.6]
      6223:     symbol=__vdso_clock_getres;  lookup in file=linux-vdso.so.1 [0]
      6223:
      6223:     file=libQt5Core.so.5 [0];  needed by /usr/lib/qt5/bin/uic [0]
      6223:     find library=libQt5Core.so.5 [0]; searching
      6223:      search path=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v3:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/haswell/x86_64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/haswell:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/haswell/x86_64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/haswell:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu          (system search path)
      6223:       trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v3/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/haswell/x86_64/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/haswell/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/haswell/x86_64/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/haswell/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:      search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      6223:      search path=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v3:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/haswell/x86_64:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/haswell:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/haswell/x86_64:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/haswell:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v3:/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2:/lib/tls/haswell/x86_64:/lib/tls/haswell:/lib/tls/x86_64:/lib/tls:/lib/haswell/x86_64:/lib/haswell:/lib/x86_64:/lib:/usr/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v3:/usr/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2:/usr/lib/tls/haswell/x86_64:/usr/lib/tls/haswell:/usr/lib/tls/x86_64:/usr/lib/tls:/usr/lib/haswell/x86_64:/usr/lib/haswell:/usr/lib/x86_64:/usr/lib            (system search path)
      6223:       trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v3/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/haswell/x86_64/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/haswell/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/haswell/x86_64/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/haswell/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v3/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/lib/tls/haswell/x86_64/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/lib/tls/haswell/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/lib/tls/x86_64/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/lib/tls/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/lib/haswell/x86_64/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/lib/haswell/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/lib/x86_64/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/usr/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v3/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/usr/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/usr/lib/tls/haswell/x86_64/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/usr/lib/tls/haswell/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/usr/lib/tls/x86_64/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/usr/lib/tls/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/usr/lib/haswell/x86_64/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/usr/lib/haswell/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:       trying file=/usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
      6223:
/usr/lib/qt5/bin/uic: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Core.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```